# Toogle entre dos checkbox HTML, JS?

Tags: javascript, html

Como estan?.

Estoy tratando de hacer algo que deberia ser simple pero me encuentro entrampado.

Tengo una grilla HTML en la cual en cada fila hay un usuario. En la ultima columna tengo que listar los mails que tiene disponibles.
Al lado de cada mail tengo un checkbox para marcar cual es el mail que se encuentra activo.

Desde la base de datos traigo inicialmente el valor para saber cual de los dos mail se encuentra activo inicialmente mediante una lista lstNotificaciones renombrada como Notif.
Cuando Notif.tipo_mail trae 1 activa el check en un mail y si trae 2 activa en el otro.

Necesito que al momento de clickear un checkbox, el otro se desactive y viceversa, para así permitir que solo un checkbox este activo y asi enviar de vuelta el valor a la DB del cual se guardo.

Por algun motivo no me resulta el cambio y el navegador me arroja "No se puede obtener la propiedad 'checked' de referencia nula o sin definir".

Esta es la parte HTML  (El valor ind es el indice o la posicion del array que indica al usuario de la lista).

Ej:

```
lstNotificaciones
 Array[1] = Usuario1....
 Array[2] = Usuario2....
 Array[3] = Usuario3....




            <TD class="texto" bgcolor="#ffffff" align="left" width="25%"> 
                            <c:choose>
                                <c:when test="${Notif.tipo_email!=1}">
                                    <input type="checkbox" id="checkmailppal<%=ind%>" onclick="setFlgMailPpal(<%=ind%>)"></input><c:out value="${Notif.email}" />
                                </c:when>
                                <c:otherwise>
                                    <input type="checkbox" checked id="checkmailppa<%=ind%>" onclick="setFlgMailPpal(<%=ind%>);" ></input><c:out value="${Notif.email}" />
                                </c:otherwise>
                            </c:choose>
                            &nbsp;
                            <c:choose>  
                                <c:when test="${Notif.tipo_email!=2}">
                                    <input type="checkbox" id="checkmailsec<%=ind%>" onclick="setFlgMailSec(<%=ind%>);"></input><c:out  value="${Notif.email_secundario}" />
                                </c:when>
                                <c:otherwise>
                                    <input type="checkbox" checked id="checkmailsec<%=ind%>" onclick="setFlgMailSec(<%=ind%>);" ></input><c:out value="${Notif.email_secundario}" />
                                </c:otherwise>
                                </c:choose>
                            </TD>
```

Esta es la parte JS.

```
function setFlgMailPpal(ind){


var checkmailppal = document.getElementById("checkmailppal"+ind);
var checkmailsec = document.getElementById("checkmailsec"+ind);

if(checkmailppal.checked == false){
    //vectoNotificaciones[ind].tipo_email = 1;
    checkmailsec.checked = true;

}else{
    //vectoNotificaciones[ind].tipo_email = 2;
    checkmailsec.checked = false;
    
}


}



function setFlgMailsec(ind){


var checkmailppal = document.getElementById("checkmailppal"+ind);
var checkmailsec = document.getElementById("checkmailsec"+ind);

if(checkmailsec.checked == false){
    //vectoNotificaciones[ind].tipo_email = 1;
    checkmailppal.checked = true;

}else{
    //vectoNotificaciones[ind].tipo_email = 2;
    checkmailppal.checked = false;
    
}


}
```

Muchas gracias!
Saludos

Comment: Pareciese ser que el ID de los elementos no está siendo renderizado como quieres... Y por eso `document.getElementById("checkmailppal"+ind);` falla y no obtiene la referencia. ¿Podrías verificar el valor de `id` de tus checkbox,  y compratirlo?

Comment: Hola FranAcuna, ahora estoy probando con el siguiente codigo: Esto para englobar los elementos del formulario with (document.PpalForm){ } Esto para retornar valores console.log("ppal "+ind+" "+ checkmailppal.checked); console.log("sec "+ind+" "+ checkmailsec.checked);` Lo que me da un resultado como: ppal 0 false sec 0 true

Ahora al momento de clickear en un check, se desactiva y activa el otro y vice versa.

Disculpa desconozco como formatear como codigo en los comentarios.

Comment: No lo agregues aquí, agrégalo en tu respuesta, solo editala con el botón. No necesitas código para ver el ID, usa chrome developer tools  sobre la página renderizada (F12 en google chrome ) o algo similar y selecciona el objeto ( en google chrome ctrl + shift + c) y podrás ver su ID.